# VS Code - after using assert, enclosed code is removed due to optimization

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest

My test code is:

```
from func import add, is_even

def test_add():
    assert add(2, 3) == 5

def test_is_even():
    assert is_even(2) == True
```

After saving this code in VS Code, following warning is showed:

> Use of assert detected. The enclosed code will be removed when
> compiling to optimised byte code.

When I run this code from terminal, I don't get any output. What I'm doing wrong? Or is there any problem with the VS Code configuration?

Comment: How do you run the code from terminal?

Comment: command: python3 filename.py

Comment: I don't remember encountering a similar issue, however the message is pretty clear, isn't it? Assert is meant for development purposes only and will be removed when compiling for production.

Comment: Use a testing framework like `pytest` or `pyunit` to do proper testing and assertions.

Comment: `assert` statements are removed if Python is called with the `-O` or `-OO` flags: `python -O myfile.py`.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if `$ python3 filename.py` is how you run your code and the code in the question is everything you have, then you won't get any output because you just defined two functions you do not call anywhere.

You also tagged the question `pytest`, so you should use `$ pytest filename.py` to run your tests. For more, see the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/getting-started.html).